# TableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles is empty

Tags: powershell, winforms, user-interface

I am giving a try to GUI in powershell. I am playing around with `TableLayoutPanel` to get an idea of how to work with it. Specifically I am trying to set columns' widths. What I do not understand is why the `ColumnStyles` collection is empty.

As I understand it there should be an entry in the collection for each column but the `Count` property is always 0. What I am doing wrong ?

Thanks for any help.

```
Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms

$main_form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$main_form.Text ='SMTP Tester'
$main_form.Width = 600
$main_form.Height = 400

$layout = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel
$layout.ColumnCount = 2
$layout.RowCount = 10
$layout.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Fill
$main_form.Controls.Add($layout)

$smtpserver_label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$smtpserver_label.Text = "SMTP Server"
$smtpserver_label.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::MiddleLeft
$layout.Controls.Add($smtpserver_label,0,0)

$smtpserver_textbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$layout.Controls.Add($smtpserver_textbox,1,0)

$port_label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$port_label.Text = "Port"
$port_label.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::MiddleLeft
$layout.Controls.Add($port_label,0,1)

$port_textbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$port_textbox.Text = "25"
$layout.Controls.Add($port_textbox,1,1)

$usetls_checkbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$usetls_checkbox.Text = "Use TLS"
$layout.Controls.Add($usetls_checkbox,0,2)

$layout.ColumnStyles.Count
$layout.ColumnStyles.Item(0).SizeType = [System.Windows.Forms.SizeType]::Absolute
$layout.ColumnStyles.Item(0).Width = 100
$layout.ColumnStyles.Item(1).SizeType = [System.Windows.Forms.SizeType]::AutoSize

$main_form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: `$layout.ColumnStyles.Add(...))`

Comment: @Jimi It indeed did the trick. I convinced myself that the ColumnStyle objects would be created by the TableLayoutPanel object itself.

Comment: @Jimi If you want to post answer I will validate it. Else I will post it myself.

Comment: Go ahead. I cannot post answers until next month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jimi pointed out in the comments, you need to manually create the ColumnStyle objects and add them to the ColumnStyles collection. The `$layout.ColumnCount` property does not allocate those objects automatically like I thought.

```
$columnstyle = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle
$res = $layout.ColumnStyles.Add($columnstyle)
$columnstyle = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle
$res = $layout.ColumnStyles.Add($columnstyle)
$layout.ColumnStyles.Item(0).SizeType = [System.Windows.Forms.SizeType]::Absolute
$layout.ColumnStyles.Item(0).Width = 100
$layout.ColumnStyles.Item(1).SizeType = [System.Windows.Forms.SizeType]::AutoSize
```